# Retrieve value from an Object which is a key in a hashmap

Tags: javascript, dictionary, hashmap

I have a **DWR** call which returns a MAP<Employee, Double>.
Employee is a class having attributes, **employeeId** and **employeeName**.

In my javascript, I m doing something like this.

```
for (var k in employees) {
    if (employees.hasOwnProperty(k)) {                  
        alert("EmployeeId : " + k.employeeId);
    }
}
```

It shows me `undefined`.

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 1):

key? the `k` is the key. maybe you meant access the value of the key:

```
var employee = employees[k]
```

if `employees[k]` contains an object with the `employeeId`, then:

```
for (var k in employees) {
    if (employees.hasOwnProperty(k)) {                   
        alert("EmployeeId : " + employees[k].employeeId);
    }
}
```

Comment: map<Employee,Double> is my hashmap. The object Employee is the key and not the value

Comment: @komalsalvi can you put in the post the hashmap?

Comment: @komalsalvi: Property names are always strings in JavaScript. Even if you use an object as key, it will be converted to a string (most likely `"[object Object]"`). So in your case you probably need two maps, `ID -> number` and `ID -> employee`.

Comment: @FelixKling That is what it is happening,It is converting the key as String, How do i use 2 maps to make it working. can u list that with and example